# itunnes connect upload app only for 4 inch (iPhone 5, iPhone 5s)

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Our binary was rejected, because the 3.5-inch iPhone does not display properly views. But we do not want to support  3.5 inches. Only the iPhone 5 and above.

How to disable 3.5 inches in itunnes connect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it isn't possible to not support 3.5" devices. Your best bet would be to use Auto Layout and setup constraints to make everything resize automatically, it will also make your life easier for the new iPhone 6 & 6 Plus with different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If i set architectures arm64 only, can it solve my problem ?

Comment: You need to keep only ARMv7s and ARM64 (remove ARMv6 & ARMv7). See [iOS Support Matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com).

Answer (score -1):

You should remove launch image for 3.5 inch if you want to support only iPhone 5 and above.